# iPHONE SDK - tableview, remembering how much it is scrolled?

Tags: iphone

i was wondering how do i do this?
I wish to make a tableview configured in a way that if i scroll down a tableview and click on one row, i will be brought to another view. But when i click a back button of some sort. i return to the tableview but still viewing that particular row. kinda like the iPod table in the iPhone? Remembering scrolled position?

i just want to know how to do the 'remembering scrolled position' part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your index path in `tableView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` before pushing the new view, use it later. This will give you the NSIndexPath pointing at the cell that was selected by the user, not necessarily give you the same position it was at before they tapped the item. So keep that in mind.

Comment: how and where do i use the indexPath?

Comment: As vodkhang said above, use selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: (he provided a link)

Answer (score 0):

Continue from jer's answer. You can use indexPath when calling this method in tableView:

[UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW11)

Comment: Can you just try it first? I think that it is too easy to find a example